# How can I convert mp4 video file to mp3 in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, avfoundation

I 'm recording a video with AVFoundation framework and save this. I want get the audio file of this video because in avfoundation I record all in the same file, but I don't know how to do this and I don't find never ask about this.

I have find a source code that merge video and audio, but not explain hoe to extract this.

how can I do this? I could change mp4 to mov if this is impossible to convert or more easy..

Thanks!

Comment: Using `ffmpeg` will be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options using the `AVFoundation` framework.

Use `AVAssetReader` + `AVAssetWriter`. Read the audio track sample buffer by sample buffer from the video file and write it out to a new file.

Use `AVComposition` + `AVAssetExportSession`.  Insert the whole audio track (`AVAssetTrack`) from the video file into an `AVMutableCompositionTrack`, and export the track to a new file.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code or provide more detail?